# Reduce factor levels in same column

Tags: r

I need to reduce the levels of a factor variable "Weapon Description" which has 80 levels, I want it as 8. I have previously used grepl when i wanted the outcome to be binary. Now as i need 8 levels, i am not sure how to proceed. Below example is how i would treat if outcome is binary. I need help extending it to 8 types.

```
crime_3yr$Weapon.Used<-ifelse(grepl(crime_3yr$Weapon.Description,pattern = "GUN|AXE|RIFLE"),"Melee","Ranged")
```

Currently, first 10 levels are:

```
    AIR PISTOL/REVOLVER/RIFLE/BB GUN"              
 [3] "ANTIQUE FIREARM"                               
 [4] "ASSAULT WEAPON/UZI/AK47/ETC"                   
 [5] "AUTOMATIC WEAPON/SUB-MACHINE GUN"              
 [6] "AXE"                                           
 [7] "BELT FLAILING INSTRUMENT/CHAIN"                
 [8] "BLACKJACK"                                     
 [9] "BLUNT INSTRUMENT"                              
[10] "BOARD"                                         
[11] "BOMB THREAT"
```

I would like it to be :

```
hand gun"              
 [3] "hand gun"                               
 [4] "Assault rifle"                   
 [5] "Assault rifle"              
 [6] "melee"                                           
 [7] "melee"                
 [8] "melee"                                     
 [9] "melee"                              
[10] "misc"                                         
[11] "misc"
```

I realize I haven't provided the 8 levels that i would like, its because i still haven't decided the final factors. I just need to know how to separate the original levels into more than 2 levels. 
The 80 levels are

```
     [2] "AIR PISTOL/REVOLVER/RIFLE/BB GUN"              
 [3] "ANTIQUE FIREARM"                               
 [4] "ASSAULT WEAPON/UZI/AK47/ETC"                   
 [5] "AUTOMATIC WEAPON/SUB-MACHINE GUN"              
 [6] "AXE"                                           
 [7] "BELT FLAILING INSTRUMENT/CHAIN"                
 [8] "BLACKJACK"                                     
 [9] "BLUNT INSTRUMENT"                              
[10] "BOARD"                                         
[11] "BOMB THREAT"                                   
[12] "BOTTLE"                                        
[13] "BOW AND ARROW"                                 
[14] "BOWIE KNIFE"                                   
[15] "BRASS KNUCKLES"                                
[16] "CAUSTIC CHEMICAL/POISON"                       
[17] "CLEAVER"                                       
[18] "CLUB/BAT"                                      
[19] "CONCRETE BLOCK/BRICK"                          
[20] "DEMAND NOTE"                                   
[21] "DIRK/DAGGER"                                   
[22] "DOG/ANIMAL (SIC ANIMAL ON)"                    
[23] "EXPLOXIVE DEVICE"                              
[24] "FIRE"                                          
[25] "FIXED OBJECT"                                  
[26] "FOLDING KNIFE"                                 
[27] "GLASS"                                         
[28] "HAMMER"                                        
[29] "HAND GUN"                                      
[30] "HECKLER & KOCH 91 SEMIAUTOMATIC ASSAULT RIFLE" 
[31] "HECKLER & KOCH 93 SEMIAUTOMATIC ASSAULT RIFLE" 
[32] "ICE PICK"                                      
[33] "KITCHEN KNIFE"                                 
[34] "KNIFE WITH BLADE 6INCHES OR LESS"              
[35] "KNIFE WITH BLADE OVER 6 INCHES IN LENGTH"      
[36] "LIQUOR/DRUGS"                                  
[37] "M-14 SEMIAUTOMATIC ASSAULT RIFLE"              
[38] "M1-1 SEMIAUTOMATIC ASSAULT RIFLE"              
[39] "MAC-10 SEMIAUTOMATIC ASSAULT WEAPON"           
[40] "MAC-11 SEMIAUTOMATIC ASSAULT WEAPON"           
[41] "MACE/PEPPER SPRAY"                             
[42] "MACHETE"                                       
[43] "MARTIAL ARTS WEAPONS"                          
[44] "OTHER CUTTING INSTRUMENT"                      
[45] "OTHER FIREARM"                                 
[46] "OTHER KNIFE"                                   
[47] "PHYSICAL PRESENCE"                             
[48] "PIPE/METAL PIPE"                               
[49] "RAZOR"                                         
[50] "RAZOR BLADE"                                   
[51] "RELIC FIREARM"                                 
[52] "REVOLVER"                                      
[53] "RIFLE"                                         
[54] "ROCK/THROWN OBJECT"                            
[55] "ROPE/LIGATURE"                                 
[56] "SAWED OFF RIFLE/SHOTGUN"                       
[57] "SCALDING LIQUID"                               
[58] "SCISSORS"                                      
[59] "SCREWDRIVER"                                   
[60] "SEMI-AUTOMATIC PISTOL"                         
[61] "SEMI-AUTOMATIC RIFLE"                          
[62] "SHOTGUN"                                       
[63] "SIMULATED GUN"                                 
[64] "STARTER PISTOL/REVOLVER"                       
[65] "STICK"                                         
[66] "STRAIGHT RAZOR"                                
[67] "STRONG-ARM (HANDS, FIST, FEET OR BODILY FORCE)"
[68] "STUN GUN"                                      
[69] "SWITCH BLADE"                                  
[70] "SWORD"                                         
[71] "SYRINGE"                                       
[72] "TIRE IRON"                                     
[73] "TOY GUN"                                       
[74] "UNK TYPE SEMIAUTOMATIC ASSAULT RIFLE"          
[75] "UNKNOWN FIREARM"                               
[76] "UNKNOWN TYPE CUTTING INSTRUMENT"               
[77] "UNKNOWN WEAPON/OTHER WEAPON"                   
[78] "UZI SEMIAUTOMATIC ASSAULT RIFLE"               
[79] "VEHICLE"                                       
[80] "VERBAL THREAT"
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is the pattern to use to reduce 80 levels to 8 ?

Comment: the pattern is like grepl function. if the values contain the words "GUN|ARM|RIFLE", it will be named as "melee", then if it contains the words "ACID|SPRAY|BLEACH", it will be named as "lethal melee" and so on.

Comment: I see none of these words in the data you've given. Please provide a sample vector consisting of all such levels. Try to add as diverse as possible to ensure the solution works on every case.

Comment: `grepl` inside a `dplyr::case_when`?

Comment: @Pasqui Could you provide an example? it need not relate to my data. such as: IF 1st set of words{apple,mango} match the records it will be classified as "1", when 2nd set of words{tomato,onion} match the records, it will be classified as "2" and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`library(dplyr)`

```
example <- data.frame(key = c(1:10), 
                      values = c("knife", "gun", "bomb", "fork", 
                                 "ball", "dog", "cat", "paper", 
                                 "redfish", "honey")
                      )
  key values
1   1  knife
2   2    gun
3   3   bomb
4   4   fork
5   5   ball
6   6    dog

example %>% 
    mutate(newValues = case_when(
        grepl(x = values, pattern = "knife|gun|bomb") ~ "weapon",
        grepl(x = values, pattern = "fork|ball|paper|honey") ~ "other",
        grepl(x = values, pattern = "cat|dog|redfish") ~ "pet",
        TRUE ~ "Unkwown")
    ) 

  key values newValues
1   1  knife    weapon
2   2    gun    weapon
3   3   bomb    weapon
4   4   fork     other
5   5   ball     other
6   6    dog       pet
```

NB: 1. if you do not want to create a new column, just re-assign the same one; 2. if you need a factor, just pipe the result of the `case_when` into a `factor`

Comment: The code works well, but i cannot seem to store the values to a new column. It just displays the results.

Comment: Yes. You need to assign the result to a new data frame: `df2 <- {put the code here}`